# Adding payment module in asp.net mvc music store example by Microsoft

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I just started learning MVC and learn quite a lot by following mvc examples and reading books . I want to modify Music Store example to add payment module like by credit card , paypal etc . Their example only include till adding to cart.
Is their any examples or tutorials on adding payment options available , I searched a lot but can't get one . I just wanted to complete this example as a Shopping Cart . I wanted to learn the basics of adding this module.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't included in the tutorial because you'll need to utilize some third-party payment processor, and the implementation will vary widely depending on which provider you choose to utilize.

I'm not sure what kind of searches you've been doing, but as long as you specify the provider you want to use, you should find plenty of documentation. Again, though, you need to specify the provider in your searches because the implementation will different for each.

For example, for Pay Pal integration, see: https://www.google.com/webhp#q=asp.net+mvc+paypal

For Stripe, see: https://www.google.com/webhp#q=asp.net+mvc+stripe+payment